# Upgrade To Hibernate 4.3.4 main method never terminates JVM not finish

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, jpa

i have to upgrade from `Hibernate 4.2.3` to `Hibernate 4.3.4` to test some `JPA 2.1` Spec. i have only change this line of `code`

Previous line:

```
final org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(hibConfiguration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
```

new Added code line

```
final org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(hibConfiguration.getProperties()).build();
```

the problem i have a main method just for test some `Criteria API` but the `main method` never finish with the latest `Hibernate Version` i have retrieve the running threads and and with the latest version the threads are as follow.

```
ThreadList:
[threadID:]2  [threadName:] Reference Handler [isDaemon:] true [isAlive:] true
[threadID:]3  [threadName:] Finalizer [isDaemon:] true [isAlive:] true
[threadID:]4  [threadName:] Signal Dispatcher [isDaemon:] true [isAlive:] true
[threadID:]5  [threadName:] Attach Listener [isDaemon:] true [isAlive:] true
[threadID:]10 [threadName:] Abandoned connection cleanup thread [isDaemon:] true [isAlive:] true
[threadID:]11 [threadName:] pool-1-thread-1 [isDaemon:] false [isAlive:] true
[threadID:]1  [threadName:] main [isDaemon:] false [isAlive:] true
```

comparing with the previous version this thread is the new one.

```
[threadID:]11 [threadName:] pool-1-thread-1 [isDaemon:] false [isAlive:] true
```

is a not a daemon according to the spec.

```
No, it is not. The virtual machine terminates if the last non-daemon thread has finished. It doesn't have to be the main thread.
```

i think this thread will not finish at least in 5 minutes.

**the problem arises only creating the HibernateSessionFactory.**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{        
    HibernateHandler handler = new HibernateHandler(true);//creates the HibernateSessionFactory
    return;//JVM not finish at this point
}
```

i want my JVM terminates with the main method finish..

what i am doing wrong..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that new `ServiceRegister` is not `closed`,`Destroyed` when `SessionFactory` is closed you have to destroy by yourself when you call.

```
getSessionFactory.close().
```

my new Hibernate Code

```
final Configuration hibConfiguration = new Configuration().configure(yourCFGPath);         
final org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new org.hibernate.boot.registry
.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
applySettings(hibConfiguration.getProperties()).build();
hibConfiguration.setSessionFactoryObserver(new SessionFactoryObserver()
{
    @Override
    public void sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactory factory){}
    @Override
    public void sessionFactoryClosed(SessionFactory factory)
    {
        ((StandardServiceRegistryImpl)serviceRegistry).destroy();
    }});                
 final org.hibernate.SessionFactory factory = hibConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

later you have to call

```
session.getSessionFactory().close();
```

i hope really helps somebody.

Comment: A lot of thanks. I didn't have any idea about that. Why hibernate people always deprecating these kind of things and no give information about new implementations (4.1, 4.2, 4.3...).? It's hard having empty javadocs Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

To find out what the thread is doing, you can take a thread dump, for instance by running your program from eclipse in debug mode, and suspending the thread.

In your specific case though, you should try invoking [`sessionFactory.close()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#close%28%29).