# Hibernate does not create the table second time and hangs

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Hi I am new to Hibernate. I am trying out a sample program,when i execute the code second time hibernate does not create the table and hangs. And when i click on the database table, the database hangs .

I am using postgresql-9.3.3-1 version and hibernate-release-4.3.4.Final.

Following are my code snippets

1.hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<session-factory>

    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">postgres</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <mapping class="com.pramati.dto.UserDetails"></mapping>

</session-factory>
```

2.My POJO class. I am using annotations in my pojo class

UserDetails.java

```
@Entity
@Table (name="USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails {

@Id
private int userId;
private String userName;
@Temporal (TemporalType.DATE)
private Date joinDate;
private String address;
private String description;

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public Date getJoinDate() {
    return joinDate;
}
public void setJoinDate(Date joinDate) {
    this.joinDate = joinDate;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

1. My Java class with a main method

I am creating a UserDetails Object and retrieving the user name from the newly created UserDetails object. Following is mj java code

public class HibernateTest {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
    userDetails.setUserId(1);
    userDetails.setUserName("Avinash");
    userDetails.setAddress("Rajeev Nagar");
    userDetails.setJoinDate(new Date());
    userDetails.setDescription("Software Engineer");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(userDetails);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    userDetails=null;
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    userDetails = (UserDetails)session.get(UserDetails.class, 1);
    System.out.println("User Name Retrieved is " + userDetails.getUserName());
    session.close();
}
```

}

For the first time when i run the above java class following is the output displayed in the console of eclipse and it creates UserDetails object

```
Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
            INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
            INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.4.Final}
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
            INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
            INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
            INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
            INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
            WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
            INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
            WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
            INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb]
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
            INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
            INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
            INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
            INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
            INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
            INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:06 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
            INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:07 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
            INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
            Hibernate: drop table USER_DETAILS cascade
            Hibernate: create table USER_DETAILS (userId int4 not null, address varchar(255), description varchar(255), joinDate date, userName varchar(255), primary key (userId))
            Mar 26, 2014 3:49:07 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
            INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
            Hibernate: insert into USER_DETAILS (address, description, joinDate, userName, userId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            Hibernate: select userdetail0_.userId as userId1_0_0_, userdetail0_.address as address2_0_0_, userdetail0_.description as descript3_0_0_, userdetail0_.joinDate as joinDate4_0_0_, userdetail0_.userName as userName5_0_0_ from USER_DETAILS userdetail0_ where userdetail0_.userId=?
            User Name Retrieved is Avinash
```

The second time i run the above code, hibernate does not create the table. Following is the output of the second run

```
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.4.Final}
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
    INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
    INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
    INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
    WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
    INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb]
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
    INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
    INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
    INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    Mar 26, 2014 3:50:52 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
    INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
    Hibernate: drop table USER_DETAILS cascade
```

It gets stuck after the line saying "drop table USER_DETAILS cascade"
Please do suggest or help me with the problem. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Try closing the sessionFactory at the end of your your main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
userDetails.setUserId(1);
userDetails.setUserName("Avinash");
userDetails.setAddress("Rajeev Nagar");
userDetails.setJoinDate(new Date());
userDetails.setDescription("Software Engineer");

SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(userDetails);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();

userDetails=null;
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
userDetails = (UserDetails)session.get(UserDetails.class, 1);
System.out.println("User Name Retrieved is " + userDetails.getUserName());
session.close();
sessionFactory.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the ID by yourself.
As you are currently hard coding the ID to 1, the second time it would fail.

The below code will generate the ID automatically.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code first let me know : -

1.Are you trying to created a table or you are trying to Insert the record in the table because after reviewing the code i can say you are inserting the record into the table.

**Hibernate Insertion : -**

1. When you are trying to insert any record in any table using
   hibernate the primary key is uniquely assigned by hibernate itself
   for your record. (You do not have to worry about the uniquer ID of
   the record.)
2. In your code your define the entity correctly but didn't specify the
   auto increment on the primary key of the entity (Table)

Your code :  -

```
@Entity
@Table (name="USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails {

@Id
private int userId;
```

It should be corrected to(so that hibernate will itself handle the insertion with unique key) : -

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```

Third wrong point in your code is you are assigning the primary key by yourself which is also wrong -

```
UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
userDetails.setUserId(1);
```

Let us know if you have futher query or doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have done the changes as suggested by you. But it still does not work. As i am running this code in eclipse i see that the code is not getting terminated. After doing some google came across this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303032/upgrade-to-hibernate-4-3-4-main-method-never-terminates-jvm-not-finish). This is the same problem i am facing

Comment: Ok..You can do one thing .....Only perfrom insertion first and reomve the logic of userDetails = (UserDetails)session.get(UserDetails.class, 1); because once you have put the @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) hibernate will not generate the 1 as primary key for the entity...so try to run only insertion logic and let me know the result

Answer (score 0):

Well done, the problem was in missing line as followed

```
session.getSessionFactory().close();
```

I had the same issue. It's fixed already ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. This is what I did in my main method:

```
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory  sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction(); 
        ...
        ...
        session.close();
        session.getSessionFactory().close();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
```

I also checks in my process list that there weren't java processes still running in the background from my previous runs. After ending those running processes, everything worked fine again.